# Best Monitor for 2023 16" MacBook Pro M2 Max and also for Future Gaming Rig?

Tags: gaming, monitors, linux, apple, macos

Just bought a fully upgraded 16" MacBook Pro running M2 Max, and as a result, am looking for a very good 4K monitor.

My configuration:

- Apple M2 Max
- 12‑core CPU
- 38‑core GPU
- 16‑core Neural Engine
- 96 GB Unified RAM

My primary use for this new laptop is for coding (am a software developer) but will be building a gaming PC for which I intend to hook up to the same monitor (within six months of time or so)...

Read on other reviews that some 4K monitors look great for gaming but for full-screen media like Netflix and YouTube there are black bars on the side... Also, read that the text size becomes unreadable (because of how small it becomes) so users are forced to downscale their settings to 1080p.

Questions:

- What would be a good monitor for my needs? I am looking at the 32" range and wish to have a 144hz to 240hz refresh rate... Also prefer OLED.
- Should I get an HDMI 2.1 cable or Thunderbolt to DisplayPort cable?
- Am interested in curved monitors as well... Any thoughts?

So, far I am looking at [LG 32QP950](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-32gq950-b-gaming-monitor) but am wondering if there's an equivalent curved display that's better.

Would appreciate any help with people who own these types (M2 Max) of Apple laptops and have bought external displays for the particular use cases I listed (writing code, watching media, and future gaming with a future PC/Linux rig).